How can I update the style of the mui tooltip on this BarChart component from @mui/x-charts
This is the BarChart component from @mui/x-charts. I've been trying to select the component through a mui class in the sx prop, but to no affect.
Here is the sx prop I used. I tried variations of class names and varying specificity.
            <BarChart
              dataset={organizedData}
              tooltip={
                {
                  trigger: 'axis',
                }
              }
              axisHighlight={{
                x: 'band', // Or 'none', or 'band'
                y: 'none', // Or 'none'
              }}
              xAxis={[{
                scaleType: 'band',
                dataKey: 'date',
                tickLabelPlacement: 'middle',
                tickPlacement: 'middle',
              }]}
              series={[
                {
                  dataKey: selectedMetric,
                  label: robotMetricLabelMap[selectedMetric].label,
                  color: tailosTheme.palette.highlight_on_paper.main,
                },
              ]}
              sx={{
                '&.base-Popper-root': {
                  '&.MuiChartsTooltip-root': {
                    'color': '#14181B !important',
                    '& td': {
                      color: '#14181B !important',
                    },
                    '&.MuiChartsTooltip-labelCell': {
                      color: '#14181B !important',
                    },
                    '&.MuiChartsTooltip-cell': {
                      color: '#14181B !important',
                    },
                  },
                },
              }}
            />

Here is the image of the tooltip. Currently the text is white and I'd like to change it to black.

